# how to solve A problem occurred configuring project Could not get unknown property in on_audio_query

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

hi i add the on_audio_query package but when i want to run the project on emulator, it shows me this error :

[image: error]

> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':on_audio_query_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   BUILD FAILED in 6s
>   Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

this is my  gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

this is my build.gradle in android folder :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

i read other solutoin in stack overflow to change the build.gradle classpath to 3.1 and 4.1.0 and gradle-wrapper but it didnt work, i also delete gradle and .gradle folder and use flutter clean command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed these and it worked
in  gradle->wrapper-> gradle-wrapper.properties :

change

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

then in android-> build.gradle

change

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

to

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}}
```

and then delete android->.gradle folder

after that I enabled multidex :
Open project/app/build.gradle and add the following lines.

defaultConfig {
...

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

}
and

dependencies {
...

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

}
If you have migrated to AndroidX, you'll want this instead (tip by Touré Holder):

dependencies {
...

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

}